# jquery highlight cell on text input

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to figure out how to have a table cell highlight when a value greater than zero is input into a text input.  I have seen plenty of examples on checkboxes but can't seem to find an example on a text input.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show us some markup or the input field. Below answer is under the assumption that input is directly inside `td`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JhUkU/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="number" />
        </td>
    <tr>        
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="number" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.number').keyup(function() {
    var number = $(this).val();

    try {
        number = parseInt(number, 10);
        if (number > 0) {
            $(this).closest('td').addClass('highlight');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('td').removeClass('highlight');
        }

    } catch (e) {}
});
```

**CSS:**

```
td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; }

td.highlight { border: 1px solid red; }

input { width: 100px; }
```

Comment: The html code you posted is correct.  I should have posted it. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the keypress event on the input and add/remove a class based on the value:

```
$('td input[type=text]').keypress(function(ev) {
    var $input = $(this);
    var $cell = $input.closest('td');

    if (Number($input.val()) > 0) $cell.addClass('highlight');
    else $cell.removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.change()` function, e.g. such as this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" />

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(val > 0) {
        $('td').addClass('highlight');
    } else {
        $('td').removeClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
td.highlight {
    background-color: cyan;   
}
```

Here's a working example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/LsA7F/